# How to Implement a Cache with Time Eviction and Fallback Using Google Guava LoadingCache

Tags: java, caching, google-guava-cache

Google Guava's Cache is awesome after I read https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

What I want to implement needs to meet the following requirements:

1. The cache for a specific key should expire after 10 mins, so that the next call to get(key) will always call `createExpensiveGraph(key)` to update and reset the timer (`expireAfterWrite` already does this I believe).
2. If the next call to `createExpensiveGraph(key)` fails due to some unexpected error, I'd still want to use the old value even the next call happens after 10 mins.

I think for 1, it's the nature of Guava's `LoadingCache`, but for 2, how can we implement it while maintaining 1?

Comment: You might consider using `refreshAfterWrite`. Otherwise you need a victim cache to remember evicted entries to recover from. `RemovalListener` is racy, so you could use a [CacheWriter](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer) instead.

Comment: @BenManes, can you help me in more details? If we use `refereshAfterWrite`, we are making unnecessary calls to the external server. If we use a victim cache, how to main the victim cache - when to expire?

Comment: These are the problems you'd face in (2) regardless. At some point you need to make a server call to ensure fresh data. You would also have to eventually evict due to memory bounds. At best you can cover the common cases but there are limits.

Comment: I don't dare to answer your question since you specifically asked for Guava. However, the problem you asked for is the default behavior in `cache2k` and the details are highly configurable, take a look at https://cache2k.org/docs/stable/user-guide.html#exceptions-and-resilience If you are okay, I can write a more comprehensive answer with some more explanation. Maybe you can alter your question and ask for alternative approaches?